# Failed to generate executive file in Visual Studio Code 2019

Tags: c++

I am new in C++. 
I encountered in question to find the vowels(i.e. "a","e","i","o","u") in a sub string,
and then I was thinking about change the driver function to get user input.
Unfortunately, this code did not generate execution file in Visual Studio Code nor any error messages.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
FYI, the function code was from GeeksforGeeks.
Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// return true if x is vowel

bool isVowel(char x){
    // function to check if x is in vowel or not
    return (x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x =='i' || x == 'o' || x=='u');
}

void(FindSubString(std::string str)){
    set<char> hash; // to store vowel
    // outer loop picks starting characters
    // and inner loop picks for ending characters
    int n = str.length();
    for (int i =0; i<n; i++){
        for (int j = i; j <n; j++){
            // if current position is not vowel, 
            // then no more possible string starting from str[i]
            if (isVowel(str[j])==false)
                break;
            // if vowel, insert into hash
            hash.insert(str[j]);

            //if all vowels are present in current substring
            if (hash.size()==5)
                cout << str.substr(i, j-i+1) << " ";

        }
        hash.clear();
    }


int main()
{
   string str = getstring("insert a string: %s\n", stdin);
   FindSubString(str);
   return 0;
}

}
```

Comment: How did you compile the .cpp file?

Comment: I haven't *thoroughly* checked your code but there are two major 'typos'. (1) `void(FindSubString(std::string str)){` should be `void FindSubString(std::string str) {` and (2) The 'hanging' line at the very end (with just the `}` in it) should be moved to *before* the line with `int main()`.

Comment: ideone says there are several compiler errors: [https://ideone.com/fq6T0E](https://ideone.com/fq6T0E) a few of these are missing includes like <set> and <iostream>

Comment: With the two changes I suggested, there are still a number of errors. You have the wrong and missing header files. You don't need `<stdio.h>` but `<iostream>`, and you need to add `#include <set>`. Then you're left with **only one** error: what is `getstring` and where do you think it comes from?

Comment: @drescherjm I'm not deliberately ignoring your comments, by the way! It's very early morning here, and I'm just playing around with OP's code in my VS.

Comment: @drescherjm As you no doubt discovered in your online compiler test, `void(FindSubString(std::string str)){` is actually not an error (although it *is* very odd-looking).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, as mentioned in the comments, there are a number of *fatal* compiler errors in your code (when I run it through Visual Studio's C++ compiler *as is*, I get 7 errors - so I'm not sure how you are seeing none).

First, you have a missing closing brace (`}`) at the end of that function (seemingly, it is *after* the body of `main`, instead). Moving the `}` from the very end of the code to its proper place at the end of the `FindSubString` function will fix that. *(This may be a copy-paste error, or you may be trying to define `main` inside `FindSubString`, but that's not allowed in `C++`.)*

Second, you have the wrong and missing header files. Generally, for `C++` programs, you should use the `<iostream>` header rather than `<stdio.h>`. The latter is generally used for `C` programs; however, it *can* be used in `C++`, but you'll *need* `<iostream>` if you want to use `std::cout` and `std::cin`. (I'm not sure if this is part of the Standard, but many implementations automatically include `stdio.h` when you include `iostream`.) You also need to `#include <set>` to make use of the `std::set` container.

And, the last of the **fatal** errors is your call to `getstring`. This is not a standard library function. So, you can either define this yourself, or just use the code in the `main` function below:

```cpp
int main()
{
    string str;
    cout << "insert a string: ";
    cin >> str;
//  string str = getstring("insert a string: %s\n", stdin);
    FindSubString(str);
    return 0;
}
```

There is also a 'peculiarity' (though not actually an *error*, as my first version of this answer suggested) in the way you define your `FindSubString` function, with the 'extra' (unneeded, and very confusing) set of parentheses. It should be just this:

```cpp
void FindSubString(std::string str)
{
```

However, even with all these errors fixed, your code does not work! This is because of a flaw in your logic, in the inner `for` loop of your `FindSubString` function. As you have it, that loop will terminate (because of the `break;` statement) on the first occurrence of a non-vowel.

You should, instead, check if the test letter ***is*** a vowel, and insert into the hash set if so. I'm not *entirely* sure what your definition of a sub-string is, but this code does something approaching what I *think* you want (feel free to clarify your goal, or correct my assumption):

```cpp
void FindSubString(std::string str)
{
    set<char> hash; // to store vowel
    int n = str.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
            if (isVowel(str[j])) hash.insert(str[j]); // if vowel, insert into hash
            //if all vowels are present in current substring
            if (hash.size() == 5)
                cout << str.substr(i, j - i + 1) << " ";

        }
        hash.clear();
    }
}
```

The code shown will find all substrings containing the five vowels.

Sample input:

```
facetiously
```

Output:

```
facetiou facetious facetiousl facetiously acetiou acetious acetiousl acetiously
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I only changed the code in the "int main() function", other codes were copied from W3chools.com, I was learning C++ that was why I followed the steps(I am taking C course so I might have mixed something together). Not including the libraries was that I really did not know what should I put. I forgot "ctrl+shift+B" after configuring so I did not get errors. I already said I am new, blaming a newbie with the language you use probably everyday was pretty surprising to me and I lost all the joy learning it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort! Those comments might be right. But hurt. I gave the credit though. I am generous on this.